# android html5 audio from contentprovider in webview

Tags: android, html, audio, webview

If I load this html5 audio tag in a webview

```
<audio src="audio/diables.m4a" controls="controls"></audio>
```

using loadDataWithBaseURL() with base url "content://my.epub.reader.content_provider", the content provider returns a ParcelFileDescriptor.

When it loads/when I click play, I hear no sound and my Android 3.2 (Galaxy Tab 10.1) system (or Android 4.0.3 emulator), log this:

```
E/MediaPlayer(19689): Unable to to create media player
E/HTML5Audio(19689): couldn't load the resource: content://my.epub.reader.content_provider/audio/diables.m4a exc: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

A html5 video tag is displaying **fine** in the webview, loading it in the same way, using the same content provider.

What could be the problem with the audio?

Comment: try with an mp3 file. <audio src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls" />

Comment: okay I will try this next week.